# How can you make the SpecFlow VS autocomplete respect step scope?

Tags: bdd, specflow

Does any one have a solution to make the SpecFlow autocomplete in Visual Studio understand feature or scenario tagging and restrict its list of choices according to step scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported currently.

Drop me a mail to gaspar.nagy/gmail, maybe I can help somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a real answer, but you're not supposed to scope steps by feature. It goes against the entire idea of reusing steps throughout all your features. The only reason you might want to scope steps is if they are intended to be treated differently (e.g. manual versus smoke versus performance).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've heard this before, but this is a large web application and if we don't scope steps by product area we are likely to end up with a huge number of different steps in the future. We would like the autocomplete to aid in reusing steps when writing features, but if there is no scoping involved the number of steps would leave this approach almost useless.